# how to fail a test in Testcomplete programmatically?

Tags: testcomplete

I am trying to programmatically fail a test in TestComplete
What code do I have to write to set a vb script test as failed in TestComplete?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Log.Error("Some error message") and change the Project properties to stop test on error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [`Runner.Halt`](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31584/) maybe?

> The `Halt` method stops the script execution and posts an error string specified by `ErrorMsg` to the test log.
>
> The method stops the entire test run, that is, for instance, if you are executing a project or project suite test, the method will stop the entire project or project suite run.

Answer (score 0):

Log.Error statements throws an error programmatically and fails the test.

Sample:-

Log.Error "Any Error message"